# Terminate bluetooth reading while loop

Tags: android

I am building an app which read data from an external device through bluetooth. Device send multiple time data and here is the snip of the code which used to read data from bluetooth.

```
while(true)
{
    inputStream.read(bytes);

  // reset of code goes below
}
```

How I terminate this loop after device not sending data.

Answer (score 0):

when your inputStream is done reading (presumably it will return null at some point or timeout... hard to know since we have no idea what the nature of your inputStream is) you will call `break` on your loop.

If you provide more details about what this read actually consists of, it will be easier to give you guidance.

In general, it's not a good idea to do `while(true)` in this sort of situation because you're setting yourself up for a situation where you're going to never exit that loop at all.

From a logical standpoint, WHY are you doing this in a loop at all?

do you maybe mean something like...

```
while((bytes = inputStream.read(someNumber)) != null){
   //do something with byte slice here
}
```

or are you worried that the connection itself might fail?  You're going to need to provide more detail as to what you're trying to achieve here.

Comment: I try to get blood pressure from device... While device find blood pressure it returns bytes and those bytes also not fix size. It varies every time form 1 to 30 most time. It send the actual reading in last 3 streams.

For last 3 run it send total bytes as following
382 , 
588 , 
316 ,

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know exactly what you mean, but if you know what the end of the read looks like (382,588,316 or whatever) then just look for those values and then break;